# How do I fix "Wireless network disabled by hardware switch"?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, networking

My Wifi network died last night. I restarted the router but it didn't help.

I have an [asus 1201n](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1201N_Seashell/) and I'm running 11.04!
I've checked the other questions on this subject but none has an answer.

[image: wifi options]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notebook can have a switch on the side with which you can block all outgoing wireless access. Example of a random notebook:

[image]

It could also be a <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> Bottom left has the Fn.

[image]

It can also be just the <kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: I AM AN IDIOT! Have bought and returned two wifi usb sticks thinking the built-in wifi had died on the laptop! The `Fn + Fm` combo worked for me.

Comment: they are stupid for giving you the option to be able to do it. users are mean, stupid and destroys what you have done.

Comment: culebron I bet you where not the 1st :D :D