# Can't turn on or enable wireless

Tags: 11.10, wireless, drivers

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 for a couple of months.

but Today after restart my laptop I can't get wireless on. I tried to install windows wireless drivers but it didn't work too.

and It's not off by `rfkill` too.

```
# rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

when I tried

```
# ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

and

```
# lshw -C network  *-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 78:2b:cb:e6:7a:ca
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f3204000-f3204fff memory:f3200000-f3203fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 34
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7a00000-f7a01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: eth2
       serial: 00:1f:1f:96:af:41
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC Ethernet Device ip=192.168.2.3 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Now where is the problem and How should I solve it?

Comment: is your hardware switch on? http://askubuntu.com/q/44863/10698

Comment: yes,and It works correctly in Windows

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-oneiric-generic
sudo reboot
```

Comment: For Ubuntu precise this would be installing `linux-backports-modules-cw-x.y-precise-generic` (where `x.y` is e.g. `3.6`) to get backported wireless modules for the regular Ubuntu kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a simple man using Ubuntu simply so I can only give you a simple answer, but have you tried looking whether you are killing your radio frequency via a Wi-Fi switch or button somewhere on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a dual boot with windows, it might be windows using the wifi card even though you have booted into linux. If you go into the power options in your windows, go to advanced options and find where the option to 'set what the power button does', disable the 'fast start' and reboot into linux. If the 'fast start' is enabled in your windows, windows keeps control of your wifi card. This may or may not be what is happening in your situation, but this had fixed my situation.

Comment: This is demonstrably false. Windows can only use hardware when Windows is booted. When Ubuntu (or any other operating system) is booted on bare metal, *only* that OS has access to the hardware.

Comment: This may be a correct solution with Win 10.